# Raster vs paint(g) , paintComponent(g)

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, raster

I'm a novice programmer and recently I came across many methods of animation:

1. Using `BufferedImages` , ie. draw to image and display using double buffering or triple buffering methods .
2. Making my sprites components by extending Component or Button . and repainting by `repaint(g)`.
3. Rastering, using rasters and integer arrays, bitmaps and the like.

I realise that method 1 and 2 are similar as they use `paint()` methods , however Rastering involves self-made functions , eg. creating functions that set background by traversing the whole array representing each pixel and setting colour to desired colour .

I've seen many folks online use raster methods **even though** 1 & 2 seem simpler .

Please help me out here guys and tell me what path i should follow and why .

Answer (score 0):

The first and second methods are very similar and would come down to the context of the problem.

The third option would, for the most part come down to providing a flexible API which was independent of the toolkit or framework which was to be used to dipslay it. One could argue that there is a speed increase, but with Swing and JavaFX working more directly with the DirectX and OpenGL pipelines, this is less of an issue.

Unless your planning on dong some seriously low level functionality or interfacing to a non-standard API I wouldn't worry to much about it (some effects painting might be faster done this way, but it's all about context)

Personally, it would focus on developing an understanding of the basics and principles involved and how they might be implemented using the first two options as it allows you to focus on those concepts with a relatively easy API

As time progress or you come across a situation that can't be resolved using these techniques, then it might be time to consider playing with the rastering approach.

Remember though, you still need to get that byte array into a format that the API wants  which in of itself, will add overheads

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I guess I'll stick to the higher-level methods and skip rastering for now . :)